# How to remove style element from page via Javascript element selector

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I've been trying to remove the next html element from a page for the next couple of hours without any success:

```
<style type="text/css" data-isostyle-id="917865">.tb_sK{display:none!important}</style>
```

I tried to remove all the styles from the page like that:

```
js = "var aa=document.getElementsByTagName(\"style\");aa.parentNode.removeChild(aa)"
driver.execute_script(js)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

That style is making an file input to not be displayed on the page , and that way i can't access the input and upload a file.

I will be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: hint: `getElements` is *plural*, not singular

Comment: @CertainPerformance how can i remove all the styles that the var contains?

Comment: Iterate over them, possibly with `forEach` if you use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByTagName`